# Enumerator fails to return the first element

Tags: c#, enumerator

I implemented the `IEnumerator` interface in my class. It works fine apart from the fact that it never returns the first element in `MyListContainer`. Only the rest. So to try and fix this I used the following:

```
public void Reset(){ EnumeratorPosition = -1; }
```

But it didn't return the first result again.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or is the first element the foreach's share?

```
public bool MoveNext()
{                
    EnumeratorPosition++;
    return (EnumeratorPosition < MyListContainer.Count);                
}

public void Reset()
{ EnumeratorPosition = 0; }

public object Current
{
    get { return MyListContainer[EnumeratorPosition]; }
}

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator)this;
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own enumerator, why not use [yield return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) which writes the code for you. Alternatively MyListContainer probably implements IEnumerable already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start `EnumeratorPosition` at -1, not 0. Then the first call to `MoveNext()` moves to the first item, not the second.

An enumerator that hasn't started enumerating yet is pointing at nothing -- at the whistling void prior to the first element.

In implementation terms, that's simple. Initialize it to `-1` in its declaration, and set it to `-1` in `Reset()`:

```
private int _enumeratorPosition = -1;
public void Reset() { _enumeratorPosition = -1; }

public bool MoveNext()
{                
    _enumeratorPosition++;
    return (_enumeratorPosition < MyListContainer.Count);                
}

public object Current
{
    get { return MyListContainer[_enumeratorPosition]; }
}
```

...and while you're at it, since it is (or very much ought to be) a private field, let's rename it to `_enumeratorPosition` so anybody reading your code will know what it is immediately.

With all that said, you could just call `MyListContainer.GetEnumerator()` instead of writing your own. It's rare for most of us to implement `IEnumerator` other than as an exercise. But it's a good exercise, so I'd hate to discourage you.

Comment: Indeed. Conceptually, an enumerator starts one before the start of the sequence.

Comment: @Broadroad How are you initializing EnumeratorPosition? You didn't show that.

Comment: @Broadroad Initialize the `EnumeratorPosition` in the constructor or in the field definition, in addition to `Reset`. (Just follow the MSDN example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That sounds promising. How does one go about that? I mean, inicializing this hungry little beast?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @Ed's answer you can move the post increment to inside the return statement:

```
return (EnumeratorPosition++ < MyListContainer.Count);
```